# Metadata Like Config file parser

Tags: c++, parsing

i am trying to parse this config file ...

```
MODEL: "modelname1" { FILEPATH = "FILEPATH1"; TEXTUREPATH = "TEXTUREPATH1"; NORMALPATH = "NORMALPATH1"; }
MODEL:"modelname2"{FILEPATH = "FILEPATH2";TEXTUREPATH = "TEXTUREPATH2";NORMALPATH = "NORMALPATH2";}
```

here is my attempt :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


struct ModelData
{
    string tagName;
    string filePath;
    string texturePath;
    string normalPath;
};

vector<ModelData> g_modelData;

void GetStringValue( string _source, string _tagName, string& _outStrVal )
{
    size_t equalPos = _source.find_first_of('=');
    string tagName = _source.substr(0, equalPos);
    tagName.erase(remove(tagName.begin(), tagName.end(), '"'), tagName.end());

    if (tagName == _tagName)
    {
        _source = _source.substr(equalPos + 1);
        _source.erase(remove(_source.begin(), _source.end(), '"'), _source.end());

        _outStrVal = _source;
    }
}

int main()
{
    ifstream infile("modeldata.txt", ios::in);
    if (!infile.good())
    {
        cout << "Error opening file!" << endl;
    }

    string line;
    line.resize(1024);

    while (infile.getline((char*)line.data(), line.size(), '\n'))
    {
        line.erase(remove(line.begin(), line.end(), ' '), line.end());
        line.erase(remove(line.begin(), line.end(), '\t'), line.end());

        size_t colonPos = line.find_first_of(':');
        string tagStr = line.substr(0, colonPos);

        if (tagStr == "MODEL")
        {
            ModelData md;

            string tagValueStr = line.substr(colonPos + 1);
            size_t tagNamePos = tagValueStr.find_first_of('{');
            string tagName = tagValueStr.substr(0, tagNamePos);
            tagName.erase(remove(tagName.begin(), tagName.end(), '"'), tagName.end());

            md.tagName = tagName;

            tagValueStr = tagValueStr.substr(tagNamePos + 1);

            size_t tagValueTerminatingPos = tagValueStr.find_first_of('}');

            tagValueStr = tagValueStr.substr(0, tagValueTerminatingPos);

            string temp;
            char context[1024];
            memset( context,0, 1024 );

            temp = strtok_s(&tagValueStr[0], ";", (char**)&context);

            GetStringValue(temp, "FILEPATH", md.filePath);

            temp = strtok_s(nullptr, ";", (char**)&context);
 
            GetStringValue(temp, "TEXTUREPATH", md.texturePath);

            temp = strtok_s(nullptr, ";", (char**)&context);

            GetStringValue(temp, "NORMALPATH", md.normalPath);

            g_modelData.push_back(md);
        }
    }

    





    infile.close();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

but what if I format the config file to

```
MODEL: "modelname1" 
{ 
    FILEPATH = "FILEPATH1"; 
    TEXTUREPATH = "TEXTUREPATH1"; 
    NORMALPATH = "NORMALPATH1"; 
}

MODEL:"modelname2"
{
    FILEPATH = "FILEPATH2";
    TEXTUREPATH = "TEXTUREPATH2";
    NORMALPATH = "NORMALPATH2";
}
```

then getline wont work and I have to do character by character parsing ...

so I wanted to ask what could be the faster implementation of the above change, i want to extract this data inside program and use it to load things.

I am ok if you want to redesign this config file for better flow.

**QUERY UPDATE:**

Would like to know more about **how to parse nested blocks and curly braces**, didn't found much in google search. my config file would then should look like ...

```
MODEL: "modelname1" 
{ 
    FILEPATH = "FILEPATH1"; 
    TEXTUREPATH = "TEXTUREPATH1"; 
    NORMALPATH = "NORMALPATH1"; 
    PLACEHOLDER = 
    {
        DATA0 = true//1
        DATA1 = 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f;
        DATA2 = 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f;
        DATA3 = 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f;
    }
}
```

should read this into

```
struct ModelData
{
    string tagName;
    string filePath;
    string texturePath;
    string normalPath;
    bool Data0;
    Vec3 Data1;
    Vec3 Data2;
    Vec3 Data3;
};
```

Comment: Bro I am accepting c implementation as well ...

Comment: Two suggestions: Use Test-Driven Development, so you can easily track your progress and avoid regressions during development. The other suggestion is to use an existing metaformat instead of inventing your own, like e.g. INI, XML, YAML, JSON.

Comment: don't want to use dependencies and other libs.

Comment: Learning how to use libs (of tested!) code is a good skill to learn. Don't waste energy on reinventing your own wheels. So I am curious why do you not want to use libs?

Comment: its about discussing and learning fundamentals ... libs can easily can get the job done but leaves you very dependent ... so plz excuse lib usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to learn fundamentals, I will only answer with outlines of solutions. Note that neither will work if you want to add block nesting to your language. For that you need a proper grammar like `boost::spirit` or similar.

##### Use `getline` to extract one block at a time:

```
std::string model_name, block_contents;
getline(infile, model_name, '{');
getline(infile, block_contents, '}');
```

##### Use a regular expression to do the same:

```
auto block_regex{ R"(MODEL\s*:\s*"(.*?)"\s*\{(.*?)\})" };
```

You can then apply a `std::regex_iterator` to get each block in sequence.

##### Parsing the block contents

Use `std::regex_iterator` with the regex `(\S+)\s*=\s*(".*?");`. Assign the results to an `std::map`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression to match strings and extract data from them.
regex is part of the standard library just as std::string and std::vector.
This is an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

struct ModelData
{
    std::string tagName;
    std::string filePath;
    std::string texturePath;
    std::string normalPath;
};

// helper function to output the content of your structure.
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const ModelData& data)
{
    os << "Model = " << data.tagName << "\n";
    os << "  filePath = " << data.filePath << "\n";
    os << "  texturePath = " << data.texturePath << "\n";
    os << "  normalPath = " << data.normalPath << "\n";
    os << std::endl;

    return os;
}

// load from a stream, so this example can use
// a stringstream instead of a filestream (doesn't change this function)
auto load_from_stram(std::istream& ifile)
{
    // More on regex here : https://regexone.com/, or to test your own regular expressions go here https://regex101.com/
    // between ( ) is a capture group and will contain the value of your variable
    // .+ wil match one or more of any character
    static std::regex model_rx{ "MODEL = (.+)" };
    static std::regex filepath_rx{ "FILEPATH = (.+)" };
    static std::regex texturepath_rx{ "TEXTUREPATH = (.+)" };
    static std::regex normalpath_rx{ "NORMALPATH = (.+)" };
    std::smatch match;

    std::vector<ModelData> models;
    std::string line;
    ModelData data;

    // read until end of file
    while (std::getline(ifile,line))
    {
        // check if a model starts,
        // condition next 3 lines MUST contain data too
        if (std::regex_search(line, match, model_rx))
        {
            // match[0] will contain full regex match
            // match[1] will contain first matched group
            data.tagName = match[1];
            for (std::size_t n = 0; n < 3; ++n)
            {
                std::getline(ifile, line);
                if (std::regex_search(line, match, filepath_rx)) data.filePath = match[1];
                if (std::regex_search(line, match, texturepath_rx)) data.texturePath = match[1];
                if (std::regex_search(line, match, normalpath_rx)) data.normalPath = match[1];
            }

            models.push_back(data);
        }
    }

    return models;
}

int main()
{
    std::istringstream ifile{ "MODEL = modelname1\nFILEPATH = FILEPATH1\nTEXTUREPATH = TEXTUREPATH1\nNORMALPATH = NORMALPATH1\n \
                               MODEL = modelname2\nFILEPATH = FILEPATH2\nTEXTUREPATH = TEXTUREPATH2\nNORMALPATH = NORMALPATH2\n" };

    auto models = load_from_stram(ifile);

    for (const auto& model : models)
    {
        std::cout << model;
    }
}
```

Comment: hmm, looks good but it assumes config file is simpler and has content in every line, I am more eager to know what for my new formatting... what to do when content is in there with pair of curly braces. what kind of data structure need to parse them.

Comment: The parsing above allows for emtpy or other lines between Models, it just assumes 3 lines follow after each model line. It is a minimalistic example after all, but I think it can get you started :)

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled upon a great tutorial about parsing a config file and that guy used tokenizer and went through character by character using tokens.

I want to know **what is the strategy behind generating token and tokenizer.**